# Get the link name of href <a> tag nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am scraping some data whos heirarchy is `/h2/a` but a's href should contain `http://www.thedomain.com`. All links are something like this:
`thedomain.com/test` and so on. Right now I get the text only but not the name of the href link itself.

For example:

```
<h2>
<a href="http://www.thedomain.com/test">Hey there</a>
<a href="http://www.thedomain.com/test1">2nd link</a>
<a href="http://www.thedomain.com/test2">3rd link</a>
</h2>
```

Here is my code:

```
html_doc.xpath('//h2/a[contains(@href, "http://www.thedomain.com")]/text()')
```

> Hey there, 2nd link, 3rd link

Whereas I want `http://www.thedomain.com/test` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `@href` instead of the `text()`:

```
//h2/a[contains(@href, "http://www.thedomain.com")]/@href
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CSS Selectors (probably easier to use than `xpath` in this case) for this purpose. You can select the `<a>` elements under `h2` using:

```
html_doc.css('h2 a')
```

This is the full working version of the code:

```
html = <<EOT
<html>
    <h2>
        <a href="http://www.thedomain.com/test">Hey there</a>
        <a href="http://www.thedomain.com/test1">2nd link</a>
        <a href="http://www.thedomain.com/test2">3rd link</a>
    </h2>
</html>
EOT

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
html_doc.css('h2 a').map { |link| p link['href'] }
# => "http://www.thedomain.com/test"
# => "http://www.thedomain.com/test1"
# => "http://www.thedomain.com/test2"
```